# Show the direct product of 2 groups with subgroups isomorphic to another group H has at least 3 distinct subgroups isomorphic to H

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$, $G_1$, $G_2$ be groups such that each $G_i$ $(i=1,2)$ has a subgroup $H_i$ isomorphic to $H$.  Prove that the direct product $G_1 \times G_2$ has at least 3 distinct subgroups isomorphic to $H$.

I have zero idea how to approach this.  I know that $H_1 \times H_2$ is subgroup isomorphic to $H$, but I don't know how to obtain the other two

EDIT: I now know that $H_1 \times H_2$ is wrong and that two groups that work are {$e_1$}x$H_2$, $H_1$x{e$_2$} are the other two, but I am unsure how to show that they are isomorphic to H since they are direct products.  Is it enough to show f(uv)=f(u)f(v)

Comment: You need to assume that the group $H$ has more than one element; the statement is incorrect if $H$ is a group of order one.

Comment: $[e_1}\times G_2$ and $G_1\times\{e_2\}$ are ***not*** isomorphic to $H,$ it's $\{e_1\}\times H_2$ and $H_1\times\{e_2\}$ that are isomorphic to $H.$ You also need a third group, and it's ***not*** $G_1\times G_2,$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two you are looking for are just the subgroups $H_1 \times \{e_2\}$ and $\{e_1\} \times H_2$, where $e_1, e_2$ are the identity elements of $G_1$ and $G_2$. If $f$ and $g$ are the isomorphisms between $H_1 \leftrightarrow H$ and $H_2 \leftrightarrow H$, respectively, then the isomorphism between $(H_1 \times \{e_2\} )\leftrightarrow H$ is $(h_1,e_1) \mapsto f(h_1)$ and the isomorphism between $(\{e_1\} \times H_2 ) \leftrightarrow H$ is $(e,h_2) \mapsto g(h_2)$.

Comment: My bad, I wrote $H_1, H_2$ instead of $G_1, G_2$ in the problem.  So in your answer should the $H_1, H_2$ be $G_1, G_2$?  Also how do I show its an isomorphism?  Is it just showing f(uv) = f(u)f(v)?

Comment: Sure, just swap out the group names. You'll have to show that it is a bijection and a homomorphism, so one part is showing that it is one-to-one and another is showing that f(uv) = f(u)f(v). $G_1 \times e_1$ is pretty simple, so don't overthink it -- it's basically a copy of $H$, just with an $e$ tacked on that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Also, your example of $G_1 \times G_2$ is not quite correct. What you should use is the subgroup of $G_1 \times G_2$ that consists only of elements $(g,g)$; where the first element is identical to the second.

Comment: Ok thank you! Does it matter that the group mentioned in your last comment could be empty?

Comment: Sorry: the elements themselves are not equal, their images under the isomorphisms are. I.e. they correspond to the same element in $H$. This is the subgroup of $G_1 \times G_2$ that consists only of elements $(f^{-1}h,g^{-1}h)$; where the first element is identical to the second under the two isomorphisms $f: G_1 \leftrightarrow H$ and $g: G_2 \leftrightarrow H$

Comment: so the subgroup I want would be J = {(x',y')| x'$\in H_1$, y' $\in H_2$, f(x')=g(y')} and this would be mapped to H as (x',y') -> f(x')?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is also the same as the map (x',y') to g(y') because of the equality condition!

Answer (score 3):

$\def\zee{\mathbb Z}$
Let's do an example:  $G_1 = H_1 = \zee$,  $G_2 = H_2 = \zee$.  and we use additive notation so the group identity is $0$.   The three copies of $ \zee$  are $$\zee \times \{0\} = \{(n, 0) : n \in \zee\},$$ 
$$\{0\} \times \zee = \{(0, n) : n \in \zee\},$$ and the *diagonal subgroup*, 
$$D = \{(n, n) :  n \in \zee\}.$$  Check that each of these is a subgroup isomorphic to $\zee$.   If you understand this example, you can understand the general case.  Important note:  $\zee \times \zee$ is *not* isomorphic to $\zee$, and in the general case neither $G_1 \times G_2$ nor $H_1 \times H_2$ is isomorphic to $H$.   In fact, if the groups are finite $H_1 \times H_2$ has order $|H_1 \times H_2| = |H|^2$, so the size is wrong.

Comment: I really don't understand this example.  Could you explain it?  I don't know how to construct the isomorphism between them.  Also if the group $G_1$x$G_2$ isn't isomorphic to H how would I come up with something else that is?

Comment: Can you think of any reasonable  map from the set of all integers to the set of all pairs of integers $(n, n)$ with both coordinates the same?

Comment: $f: \mathbb{Z} ->\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, $f(n) = (n,n)$?

Comment: Exactly.  Now look at the definition of isomorphism and check whether $f$ is an isomorphism.